# Redrawing Polylines in SQL on android screen orientation change

Tags: java, android, sql, android-studio, orientation

I'm not sure what the problem is here, but this app tracks your route as you move via location data. What i'm trying to figure out is why when my screen orientation changes while tracking the line disappears and stops tracking. The idea is that I can store my route into SQL in onSavedInstanceState and restore it in onRestoreInstanceState when the screen orientation changes. It's not working for some reason.

Variables and onCreate (MainActivity)

```
private static final long INTERVAL = 1000;
private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000;
private static final long SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT = 1;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private Location mCurrentLocation;
private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
public GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public Polyline line;
public static ArrayList<LatLng> Points;
public DatabaseHelper database = new DatabaseHelper(this);

protected void createLocationRequest(){
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    createLocationRequest();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(API)
            .build();
}
```

Store the LatLng points while tracking and drawing a line.

```
public Boolean isTracking = false;

public void startNewRoute(View view) {
    Points = new ArrayList<>();
    isTracking = true;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    double lng = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

    if (isTracking){
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 18));
        Points.add(latLng);
        drawLine();
    }
}
public void drawLine(){
    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions()
            .width(5)
            .color(Color.BLUE)
            .geodesic(true);

    for(int a = 0; a < Points.size(); a++){
        LatLng point = Points.get(a);
        double lat = point.latitude;
        double lng = point.longitude;
        Log.d(TAG, "Drawline point got: Lat: "+lat+", Lng: "+lng);
        options.add(point);
        line = mMap.addPolyline(options);
    }
}
```

In onSaveInstanceState saving the points from the ArrayList into the database.

```
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    String routeID = "SavedInstance";
    for (int a = 0; a < Points.size(); a++) {
        LatLng point = Points.get(a);
        double lat = point.latitude;
        double lng = point.longitude;
        database.insertSaveInstancePoints(routeID, lat, lng);
        Log.d(TAG, "Point inserted, RID: " + routeID + ", Lat: " + lat + " Lng: " + lng);
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Here's insertSavedInstancePoints() from the SQL database. (DatabaseHelper)

```
    public void insertSaveInstancePoints(String routeID, double lat, double lng){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(colSavedID, routeID);
    cv.put(colSavedLat, lat);
    cv.put(colSavedLng, lng);
    db.insert(savedInstanceTable, null, cv);
    db.close();
}
```

Then Finally Restoring the Instance State. (MainActivity)

```
 protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Points = new ArrayList<>();
    database.getSavedPoints();
    drawLine();
}
```

getSavedPoints() (DatabaseHelper)

```
 public void getSavedPoints(){
    map = new MapsActivity();
    Log.d(TAG, "getSavedPoints called!");
    String query = "SELECT "+colSavedID+", "+colSavedLat+", "+colSavedLng+" FROM "+savedInstanceTable;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    for(int a = 0; a < c.getCount(); a++) {
        double lat = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(colSavedLat));
        double lng = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(colSavedLng));
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        map.addToPointsArray(latLng);
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    deleteSavedTableData();
    c.close();
    db.close();
}
```

Add points to array (MainActivity)

```
 public void addToPointsArray(LatLng latLng){
    Points.add(latLng);
    Log.d(TAG, "Point Added to Array from DB! " + latLng);
}
```

And right now when the screen orientation changes while tracking, it crashes and the logcat says this:

```
 12-30 11:29:18.035 29721-29721/com.example.jared.backtrack D/MapsActivity:      Drawline point got: Lat: 47.510955, Lng: -122.1862465
 12-30 11:29:18.045 29721-29721/com.example.jared.backtrack D/MapsActivity: Drawline point got: Lat: 47.5108991, Lng: -122.186089
 12-30 11:29:18.045 29721-29721/com.example.jared.backtrack D/MapsActivity: Drawline point got: Lat: 47.5109001, Lng: -122.1861128
 12-30 11:29:18.055 29721-29721/com.example.jared.backtrack D/MapsActivity: Drawline point got: Lat: 47.5109044, Lng: -122.1861483
 12-30 11:29:20.085 29721-29721/com.example.jared.backtrack D/MapsActivity: Drawline point got: Lat: 47.510955, Lng: -122.1862465
 12-30 11:29:20.085 29721-29721/com.example.jared.backtrack D/MapsActivity: Drawline point got: Lat: 47.5108991, Lng: -122.186089
 12-30 11:29:20.085 29721-29721/com.example.jared.backtrack D/MapsActivity: Drawline point got: Lat: 47.5109001, Lng: -122.1861128
 12-30 11:29:20.085 29721-29721/com.example.jared.backtrack D/MapsActivity: Drawline point got: Lat: 47.5109044, Lng: -122.1861483
 12-30 11:29:20.095 29721-29721/com.example.jared.backtrack D/MapsActivity: Drawline point got: Lat: 47.5109081, Lng: -122.1861328
 12-30 11:29:22.225 29721-29721/com.example.jared.backtrack D/MapsActivity: Point inserted, RID: SavedInstance, Lat: 47.510955 Lng: -122.1862465
 12-30 11:29:22.235 29721-29721/com.example.jared.backtrack D/MapsActivity: Point inserted, RID: SavedInstance, Lat: 47.5108991 Lng: -122.186089
 12-30 11:29:22.265 29721-29721/com.example.jared.backtrack D/MapsActivity: Point inserted, RID: SavedInstance, Lat: 47.5109001 Lng: -122.1861128
 12-30 11:29:22.295 29721-29721/com.example.jared.backtrack D/MapsActivity: Point inserted, RID: SavedInstance, Lat: 47.5109044 Lng: -122.1861483
 12-30 11:29:22.305 29721-29721/com.example.jared.backtrack D/MapsActivity: Point inserted, RID: SavedInstance, Lat: 47.5109081 Lng: -122.1861328
 12-30 11:29:22.405 29721-29721/com.example.jared.backtrack I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 8489038
 12-30 11:29:22.455 29721-29721/com.example.jared.backtrack D/DatabaseHelper: getSavedPoints called!
 12-30 11:29:22.465 29721-29721/com.example.jared.backtrack D/MapsActivity: Point Added to Array from DB! lat/lng: (47.510955,-122.1862465)
 12-30 11:29:22.465 29721-29721/com.example.jared.backtrack D/MapsActivity: Point Added to Array from DB! lat/lng: (47.5108991,-122.186089)
 12-30 11:29:22.475 29721-29721/com.example.jared.backtrack D/MapsActivity: Point Added to Array from DB! lat/lng: (47.5109001,-122.1861128)
 12-30 11:29:22.475 29721-29721/com.example.jared.backtrack D/MapsActivity: Point Added to Array from DB! lat/lng: (47.5109044,-122.1861483)
 12-30 11:29:22.475 29721-29721/com.example.jared.backtrack D/MapsActivity: Point Added to Array from DB! lat/lng: (47.5109081,-122.1861328)
 12-30 11:29:22.505 29721-29721/com.example.jared.backtrack D/MapsActivity: Drawline point got: Lat: 47.510955, Lng: -122.1862465
 12-30 11:29:22.505 29721-29721/com.example.jared.backtrack D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
 12-30 11:29:22.505 29721-29721/com.example.jared.backtrack W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e92d88)
 12-30 11:29:22.515 29721-29721/com.example.jared.backtrack E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

So you can see from my debug log that it's tracking the route, lines are being drawn, When the screen rotates the points are successfully loaded into SQl then retrieved. And once it starts the drawline method it tries to draw the first point, crashes and it says nullpointer exception.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @BG_NE we figured out that the problem was that my mMap GoogleMap Object wasn't being initialized during onRestoreInstanceState() so the drawLine() method was pointing to null because there was no map.

So the solution was to move drawLine() from onRestoreInstanceState() to onMapReady() and pass a Boolean to check if something's being restored or not.

Here's the code:

```
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

/////Set restorePoints to true.
    restorePoints = true;           
    Points = database.getSavedPoints();
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);

///// Here I draw the line during onMapReady();
    if(restorePoints){
        drawLine();
        restorePoints = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're instantiating a new MapsActivity (this is what you're calling MainActivity in your question I assume?) in #getSavedPoints and setting the data on that instance. That instance is not what is shown on the screen after being recreated by the system on rotation.

Instead, make #getSavedPoints return the ArrayList of points, and set that to the Points field in your activity.

```
public List<LatLng> getSavedPoints(){
  List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList();
  Log.d(TAG, "getSavedPoints called!");
  String query = "SELECT "+colSavedID+", "+colSavedLat+", "+colSavedLng+" FROM "+savedInstanceTable;
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
  c.moveToFirst();
  for(int a = 0; a < c.getCount(); a++) {
    double lat = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(colSavedLat));
    double lng = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(colSavedLng));
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    points.add(latLng);
    c.moveToNext();
  }
  deleteSavedTableData();
  c.close();
  db.close();
  return points;
}
```

In onRestoreInstanceState

```
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  Points = database.getSavedPoints();
  drawLine();
}
```

Also, you can do this without having to use a database. If your LatLng class is just a class of two doubles, make it implement Parcelable and then you can just put/retrieve the Points object in the bundle in onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState. There is a little setup with implementing Parcelable, but it should be pretty easy to figure out.

The above is just a suggestion, if you aren't noticing a bottleneck in performance by using the database, then just stick with what's working.

Comment: This makes total sense and I got a little further, but now I get a nullpointer exception in the 'drawLine()' method being called from 'onRestoreInstance State()'. All the points load into the array fine but when it goes to actually draw the line it fails. The line is: 'line = mMap.addPolyline(options);' The GoogleMap object mMap gets created in 'onMapReady()' does that even get called in 'onRestoreInstanceState()'?

Comment: Nope, onRestoreInstanceState will not reinit things on its own. Can you move the call to drawLine to onMapReady (after the mMap object is initialized/created) and remove it from onRestoreInstanceState?

Comment: Yes!!! it worked! thank you! I just created a boolean to tell if points were being restored or not, and called just the drawline in onMapReady if it was true! Thanks, this has been a week long problem for me... lol